# OWIN Cookie Authentication - Impersonation to SQL Server with Kerberos Delegation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, kerberos, wif

After weeks of research on Identity 2.0, impersonation, delegation and Kerberos, I am still unable to find a solution that will allow me to impersonate the ClaimsIdentity user I have created using OWIN in my MVC application. The specifics to my scenario are as follows.

Windows Authentication is disabled + Anonymous enabled.
I am using an OWIN startup class to manually authenticate the user against our Active Directory. Then I pack up some of the properties into a cookie which is available throughout the rest of the application. [This](https://tech.trailmax.info/2016/03/using-owin-and-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/) is the link I referenced when setting up these classes.

Startup.Auth.cs

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
     AuthenticationType = MyAuthentication.ApplicationCookie,
     LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
     Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider(),
     CookieName = "SessionName",
     CookieHttpOnly = true,
     ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CookieLength"]))
});
```

AuthenticationService.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
    using System.DirectoryServices;
    using System.Security.Claims;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Linq;

    namespace mine.Security
    {
        public class AuthenticationService
        {
            private readonly IAuthenticationManager _authenticationManager;
            private PrincipalContext _context;
            private UserPrincipal _userPrincipal;
            private ClaimsIdentity _identity;

        public AuthenticationService(IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        {
            _authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check if username and password matches existing account in AD. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="username"></param>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public AuthenticationResult SignIn(String username, String password)
        {

            // connect to active directory
            _context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
                                            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LdapServer"].ConnectionString,
                                            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LdapContainer"].ConnectionString,
                                            ContextOptions.SimpleBind,
                                            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LDAPUser"].ConnectionString,
                                            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LDAPPass"].ConnectionString);

            // try to find if the user exists
            _userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(_context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);

            if (_userPrincipal == null)
            {
                return new AuthenticationResult("There was an issue authenticating you.");
            }

            // try to validate credentials
            if (!_context.ValidateCredentials(username, password))
            {
                return new AuthenticationResult("Incorrect username/password combination.");
            }

            // ensure account is not locked out
            if (_userPrincipal.IsAccountLockedOut())
            {
                return new AuthenticationResult("There was an issue authenticating you.");
            }

            // ensure account is enabled
            if (_userPrincipal.Enabled.HasValue && _userPrincipal.Enabled.Value == false)
            {
                return new AuthenticationResult("There was an issue authenticating you.");
            }

            MyContext dbcontext = new MyContext();
            var appUser = dbcontext.AppUsers.Where(a => a.ActiveDirectoryLogin.ToLower() == "domain\\" +_userPrincipal.SamAccountName.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (appUser == null)
            {
                return new AuthenticationResult("Sorry, you have not been granted user access to the MED application.");
            }

            // pass both adprincipal and appuser model to build claims identity
            _identity = CreateIdentity(_userPrincipal, appUser);
            _authenticationManager.SignOut(MyAuthentication.ApplicationCookie);
            _authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, _identity);


            return new AuthenticationResult();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates identity and packages into cookie
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userPrincipal"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private ClaimsIdentity CreateIdentity(UserPrincipal userPrincipal, AppUser appUser)
        {

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(MyAuthentication.ApplicationCookie, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "Active Directory"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, userPrincipal.GivenName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, userPrincipal.Surname));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userPrincipal.SamAccountName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userPrincipal.SamAccountName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Upn, userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName));


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userPrincipal.EmailAddress))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userPrincipal.EmailAddress));
            }

            // db claims
            if (appUser.DefaultAppOfficeId != null)
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("DefaultOffice", appUser.AppOffice.OfficeName));
            }

            if (appUser.CurrentAppOfficeId != null)
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Office", appUser.AppOffice1.OfficeName));
            }

            var claims = new List<Claim>();
            DirectoryEntry dirEntry = (DirectoryEntry)userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject();

            foreach (string groupDn in dirEntry.Properties["memberOf"])
            {
                string[] parts = groupDn.Replace("CN=", "").Split(',');
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, parts[0]));
            }

            if (claims.Count > 0)
            {
                identity.AddClaims(claims);
            }


            return identity;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Authentication result class
        /// </summary>
        public class AuthenticationResult
        {
            public AuthenticationResult(string errorMessage = null)
            {
                ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
            }

            public String ErrorMessage { get; private set; }
            public Boolean IsSuccess => String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

That part seems to work just fine.  However, I am required to be able to impersonate the ClaimsIdentity when making calls to the database because the database has role level security setup on it.  I need the connection to be done under the context of the ClaimsIdentity for the remainder of that user's session.

- I have set up the SPN for Kerberos and I know it works.  This app was
  previously windows auth with the Kerberos delegation and it worked properly.
- The app pool is running under the service account used in the SPN which does have delegation permissions.
- The Identity object I created is pretty much only being used within the application context.  What I mean by that is I am getting all necessary properties from mostly Active directory, but there will be two that will be created from the database.  This identity is not mapped directly to an sql table or any other data source.

Can someone help point me towards an example where I am able to impersonate the ClaimsIdentity object when making the database queries to the SQL Server database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SOLVED Update 2-1-19]** I have written a blog post detailing this process and it is available [here.](https://blog.buzzword-cloud.com/post/OWIN-cookie-authentication-w-impersonation-to-SQL-server-using-Kerberos-delegation1)

I was able to accomplish this by doing the following. I created a class to make these methods reusable.  In that class i used the `System.IdentityModel.Selectors` and `System.IdentityModel.Tokens` library to generate a `KeberosReceiverSecurityToken` and stored it in memory.

```
public class KerberosTokenCacher
{
    public KerberosTokenCacher()
    {

    }

    public KerberosReceiverSecurityToken WriteToCache(string contextUsername, string contextPassword)
    {
        KerberosSecurityTokenProvider provider =
                        new KerberosSecurityTokenProvider("YOURSPN",
                        TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation,
                        new NetworkCredential(contextUsername.ToLower(), contextPassword, "yourdomain"));

        KerberosRequestorSecurityToken requestorToken = provider.GetToken(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KerberosTokenExpiration"]))) as KerberosRequestorSecurityToken;
        KerberosReceiverSecurityToken receiverToken = new KerberosReceiverSecurityToken(requestorToken.GetRequest());

        IAppCache appCache = new CachingService();
        KerberosReceiverSecurityToken tokenFactory() => receiverToken;

        return appCache.GetOrAdd(contextUsername.ToLower(), tokenFactory); // this will either add the token or get the token if it exists

    }

    public KerberosReceiverSecurityToken ReadFromCache(string contextUsername)
    {
        IAppCache appCache = new CachingService();
        KerberosReceiverSecurityToken token = appCache.Get<KerberosReceiverSecurityToken>(contextUsername.ToLower());

        return token;
    }

    public void DeleteFromCache(string contextUsername)
    {
        IAppCache appCache = new CachingService();
        KerberosReceiverSecurityToken token = appCache.Get<KerberosReceiverSecurityToken>(contextUsername.ToLower());

        if(token != null)
        {
            appCache.Remove(contextUsername.ToLower());
        }
    }

}
```

Now when users login using my AuthenticationService, I create the ticket and store it in memory.  When they log out I do the reverse and remove the ticket from cache.  The final part (which i am still looking for a better way to accomplish this), I added some code to the constructor of my dbcontext class.

```
public MyContext(bool impersonate = true): base("name=MyContext")
{
    if (impersonate)
    {
        var currentUsername = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User?.Identity?.Name;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentUsername)){

            KerberosTokenCacher kerberosTokenCacher = new KerberosTokenCacher();
            KerberosReceiverSecurityToken token = kerberosTokenCacher.ReadFromCache(currentUsername);

            if (token != null)
            {
                token.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
            }
            else
            {
                // token has expired or cache has expired so you must log in again
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Login/Logoff");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Obviously its definitely not perfect, but it allows me to use Owin Cookie Authentication against active directory and have a Kerberos ticket generated allowing the connection to the SQL database to be under the context of the user who was authenticated.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question but:

For a SQL server connection to be made using Windows Authentication, the connection string has to use 'Integrated Security' which means it will use the current security context that is making the connection. Normally that would be your AppPool user which in your case is the Service Account. As far as I know, [you can't propagate your impersonation to the AppPool thread automatically using Kerberos auth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx). Here is the quote I found:

> In IIS, only Basic Authentication logs users on with a security token
>   that flows across the network to a remote SQL server. By default,
>   other IIS security modes used in conjunction with the identity
>   configuration element settings will not result in a token that can
>   authenticate to a remote SQL Server.

So if you want to impersonate other users, you would have to start a new Thread under the principal of the user which you are impersonating. That way the Integrated Security connection will use that user's Windows Auth to connect to SQL Server.

I'm not sure exactly how to do that but here's something that might push you in the right direction:

```
public void NewThreadToRunSQLQueries(object claimsIdentity) {
    if (claimsIdentity as ClaimsIdentity == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("claimsIdentity");
    }

    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)claimsIdentity;
    var claimsIdentitylst = new ClaimsIdentityCollection(new List<IClaimsIdentity> { claimsIdentity });
    IClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentitylst);
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal; //Set current thread principal

    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Integrated Security=True;")) 
    {
        connection.Open(); //Open connection under impersonated user account
        //Run SQL Queries
    }
}

Thread thread = new Thread(NewThreadToRunSQLQueries);
thread.Start(_identity);
```

### **Edit:**

Regarding your comment on how to make this structure "global", assuming you have access to the **HttpContext** in your authentication handler, you could do this:

```
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(_identity);

Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
     HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
}
```

So theoretically the worker thread from IIS should now run under the authenticated user (impersonation). And Trusted Connections to SQL Server should be possible. I say theoretically because I haven't tried it myself. But worst case you could grab the claim from the HttpContext to start a seperate thread like in my example above. But if this works by itself you won't even have to start a new thread like I initially mentioned.

Comment: So I am not using Windows Auth.  I am using OWIN and a Authenitcation service to check against AD manually to verify the credentials.  From there i was trying to use something like the Kerberostokenprovider or some other library to help me impersonate the claims identity i had built from that authentication service.  The link you mentioned i have run across, but im not sure if that applies to the way I am trying to do it.  but lets say that the thread.start(_identity) works for impersonation, can you point me to a way to wrap my data context to handle this globally?

Comment: I'm don't know exactly where in the ASP.NET pipeline you injected your custom authentication but usually you would have access to the *HttpContext* from your handler. So you can create a new `ClaimPrincipal` object and assign it to the context like so: `HttpContext.Current.User = principal;`. This was you can also use other things like the `[Authorize]` attributes in your controller because the whole ASP.NET application will now know about the authenticated user. I'll add an example to my answer above.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you're missing the configuration point in IIS, You need to allow IIS to pass that user context on to you, this is not the default.

Have a look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754628(v=ws.10)) before you try and "fix" your code. If this doesn't help let us know and tell us your setup, the code alone may not do the trick.

Comment: perhaps this link is also helpful, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/surajdixit/2018/02/07/kerberos-configuration-manager-for-internet-information-services-server/

Comment: Guys, in the question he clearly says that he has turned off  Windows Authentication and cannot turn it on. But you're both sharing articles where in the first step it literally says "turn on windows authentication"

Comment: Short of self-hosting, there is no way to bypass the way windows server works. You need to pass the user token to the process running the hosted application. After the request is anonymised you'd need to find a 0day exploit to get to the user and execute in that user's code. There are a lot of hackers that would love to execute on the servers in a "users" context.